# GeoJSON won't show in Internet Explorer, but works fine in FireFox

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, browser, internet-explorer

I am trying to display a simple, rather small GeoJSON file in an OpenLayers project, just about 20 polygons (a small showcase, the focus is more on tiled imagery than on the GeoJSON). I created the GeoJSON with QGIS from an existing shapefile and cut off all attribute data (I also validated it online to be sure)

This is the actual website (containing the GeoJSON showing city districts, and two tiled planning documents that are disabled by default):

http://www.anderka-stadtentwicklung.de/maps/penzberg/webmap.html

(sorry for the abysmal performance, my webhost is moving his server farm this week)

A quick link to the actual JS map code:

http://www.anderka-stadtentwicklung.de/maps/penzberg/webmap_code.js

The polygons in questions are shown in orange, at least in Firefox. But soon I noticed that the GeoJSON wasn’t visible when I viewed the map in IE9 (neither in normal mode, nor in any of the various legacy and development modes). There is no error message, and everything else works fine. I already checked all the usual suspects (trailing commas, projection, proxy problems etc.), none of it helped. JS isn't really my strongest skill, but I think my code is more or less valid, because Firebug won't point out any glaring errors, and the map is showing up correctly in FF...

The JS code itself mostly stems from a former project of mine (loosely based on an example from Erik Hazzards great book), plus various snippets I gathered up here on this page, some of the OpenLayers tutorials and different Q&A sites on the web.

Right now I am also using the OpenLayers 2.12 full feature .js file to avoid any unintended side effects due to missing features (the long-term goal is to create a slim custom openlayers.js, of course).

Why won’t the geoJSON show in IE?

Answer (score 2):

This is working in IE10 (Windows 8), I did see the black outlining in IE9 (Windows 7)

So it must be a bug in IE9 Rendering.

You can emulate a working IE9 by using
**"IE=EmulateIE8"**

see the accepted answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge

[image]